# Changes on GUI (design mode are applied) but when I build the exe changes are not applied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-interface

Im working on a C# project and the main window has tabs and a menu on the top. I wanted to add some style to the program and I added some icons and change the colors. Everything is fine in design mode because I can see the changes that I'm doing, But for some reason when I build the program or run debug mode or release everything changes(including the top) except the content of the tabs.The tabs are not locked and also I can see the change in the design mode as I said. any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting all the control's anchors right... if you don't you're likely to get all the controls missplaced on runtime.

What is "the top"?? If you mean that the tab bar changes the order of the content (but still keeps the same content) then perhaps you could tell us what kind of tab are you using... .NET's? a 3rd party?

Can you give us some snapshop of what you see in design mode vs. what you get after you compile?

Comment: I mean on the top I have several icons as on the tabs, the difference is that the icons on the top changes and those icons inside the tabs are not changing. (but on the design mode I can see all the changes).

Comment: And what is the result you get?

Comment: Try deleting everything in the output folder (except for any project dependencies) and recompiling again.

Comment: If that doesn't work you can try renaming the controls. This would cause the controls entries on the resx to be dropped and recreated which could then fix it.

Comment: it didn't work deleting everything in the output folder. How can I rename the controls?

Comment: In Design view right click the control, click on properties and the "Properties Pane" should show, look for the property called "(Name)" and change it's value.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that with some changes (such as column sizes in a `ListView`) the changes are not always applied.  What seemed to work for me was closing the design view and opening is up again.  Probably also had something to do with the fact that my `view` (interface) was a `UserControl` that required rebuilding.